# how to pass a string to a .NET worker service?

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have a worker service in .NET 5, that will monitor a folder on a PC and a MAC.

I would need the end user to pass the folder to watch to the service worker.

I saw the `override void OnCustomCommand(int command)`
but it's only for an int.

Any idea on how the end user can pass the folder to the service?

Comment: What kind of application you are developing, a service, web, console?

Comment: a worker service in .NET 5, it's like windows service on windows

Comment: Process interop required, a named pipe is the usual choice.

Comment: @HansPassant is it possible for a end user with a command prompt or power shell something like Get-Service "CustomCommandService").ExecuteCommand(128) ?

Comment: State your requirements in the question to avoid getting help you don't want.

Comment: As @HansPassant point, your requirements are unclear. Services/demons by definition, only receive prams through arguments or in an internal endpoint that the service expose to achieve this reception.

Comment: That seems like the kind of configuration that might go in `appsettings.json`.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes I think it would be the simplest way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use one of the next two approaches.

**First approach**: Pass the file path through `appsettings.json` file like this example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => {
        //Obtain the enviroment
        IHostEnvironment env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        //Append the files nedded for each enviroment 
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Local.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

Then in the `Worker` class you could inject the configuration:

```
private string _pathToFile;
public Worker(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Worker> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    //Get the path needed from configuration
    _pathToFile = configuration.GetSection("PathToFile").Value;
}
```

The **second approach** is getting this by as a service argument (this is more common approach to execute a service/daemon):

```
internal static string PathToFile;
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 0) throw new Exception("The service require the path to de watching file as an argument to start.");
    PathToFile = args[0];
    if (!File.Exists(PathToFile)) throw new FileNotFoundException("The file don´t exist",PathToFile);
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

Then access to it in the `Worker` class:

```
private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
private string _pathToFile;

public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    //Access the file loaded by argument 
    _pathToFile = Program.PathToFile;
}
```